# How to get the ID of an inserted record in HANA back to SAPUI5 application?

Tags: odata, sapui5, hana, hana-xs

I got an SAPUI5-application in which I create entries and save them via OData-service. That works, the code for the create operation can be found below. What I have to do now is, I need the ID of the inserted record in HANA back in my application. So what I did I implemented a success handler and thought I would get back this ID in the response from my OData-service. But that is not the case, I get back the same value I provided, in this case 0 since this just a dummy value for the OData-service. I did some research on how to tackle this problem, but none of the approaches worked. So I hope someone of you can help me out or got a hint how to do this. Below the code for create-operation, odata-service and the create.xsjs:

Create-operation in SAPUI5:

```
this.getOwnerComponent().getModel("Mitarbeiter").create("/ARB", oEntry, {
                success: function(oData, response){
                    console.log(response);
                    }
                });
```

OData-service:

```
service {

"MITARBEITERABTEILUNG"."ABTEILUNG" as "ABT" navigates ("Mitarbeiter" as "ARB");

"MITARBEITERABTEILUNG"."Mitarbeiter" as "ARB" create using "public.MitarbeiterAbteilung:mitarbeiterMethods.xsjslib::mitarbeiterCreate";

    association "Mitarbeiter"
    principal "ABT"("ID")
    multiplicity "1"
    dependent "ARB"("Abteilung")
    multiplicity "*";
}
```

Create.xsjs:

```
function mitarbeiterCreate(param) {
    let aAfterTableName = param.afterTableName;
    var oEntry = {};

    try {
        var statement = param.connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM\"" + aAfterTableName + "\"");
        var rs = statement.executeQuery();

        var statement2 = param.connection.prepareStatement('SELECT "MITARBEITERABTEILUNG"."MASEQUENCE".NEXTVAL from dummy');
        var rs2 = statement2.executeQuery();
        while (rs2.next()) {
            oEntry.ID = rs2.getInteger(1);
        }

        statement2.close();

        while (rs.next()) {
            oEntry.Name = rs.getString(2);
            oEntry.Adresse = rs.getString(3);
            oEntry.bz = rs.getString(4);
            oEntry.Abteilung = rs.getInteger(5);
        }

        statement = param.connection.prepareStatement('INSERT INTO "MITARBEITERABTEILUNG"."Mitarbeiter" VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)');
        statement.setInteger(1, oEntry.ID);
        statement.setString(2, oEntry.Name);
        statement.setString(3, oEntry.Adresse);
        statement.setString(4, oEntry.bz);
        statement.setInteger(5, oEntry.Abteilung);
        statement.execute();

        statement.close();

    } catch (e) {
        statement.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: The created entity should be returned by the server in the response which will have the id... and it would be in your `oData` variable of your success handler, not in your `response` variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answered in the SAP Community here: https://answers.sap.com/questions/566957/how-to-get-the-id-of-an-inserted-record-in-hana-ba.html

---

> The only thing you need to do, is to update the ID value in the "afterTableName" table provided by the function parameter. Something like that:

```
let statement = param.connection.prepareStatement('update "' + param.afterTableName + '" set ID = ' + oEntry.ID);
statement.executeUpdate();
```

> Of course that needs to be done after you have determined your new ID. In case your column name is not "ID", please replace it with the real column name.